# Image upload amazon s3 android SDK 2.0

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload an image to an amazon s3 bucket in android.
I don't get any errors but it's just not working can anybody help me?
I can't find any good examples or questions about this.

I assign a image to 'File images3'

```
images3 = new File(uri.getPath());

public void addEventToDB(){

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), // get the context for the current activity
                            "...",
                            "us-east-1:...",
                            "arn:aws:iam::...:role/Cognito_WitpaAuth_DefaultRole",
                            "arn:aws:iam::...:role/Cognito_WitpaAuth_DefaultRole",
                            Regions.US_EAST_1
                    );

                    String bucket_name = "witpa";
                    String key = "images.jpeg";

                    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
                    transferManager.upload(bucket_name, key, images3);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

    }
```

I created my bucket, in the permissions I set that everyone can write and read.

In amazon cognito I just left everything as default.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the TransferManager sample? https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. Since i had the same issue that you faced.

I have fixed by using the below code.

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
size = inputStream.available();
metadata.setContentLength(size);
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
Upload upload = transferManager.upload(bucket_name, key, images3, metadata);
upload.waitForCompletion();
```

Comment: How do tou get the real filepath from the image you selected?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way to download image and upload image in s3 amazon. you make a simple class use this WebserviceAmazon

```
public class WebserviceAmazon extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String mParams;
private String mResult = "x";
WebServiceInterface<String, String> mInterface;
private int mRequestType;
private  String UserId;
private Context mContext;


public WebserviceAmazon(Context context,String imagePath,String AppId,int type) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mParams = imagePath;
    this.mRequestType = type;
    this.UserId = AppId;
}

public void result(WebServiceInterface<String, String> myInterface) {
    this.mInterface = myInterface;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String ACCESS_KEY ="abc..";
    String SECRET_KEY = "klm...";

    try {
        if (mRequestType == 1) { // POST
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "imageName", new File(mParams));
            s3Client.putObject(request);

            mResult = "success";
        } if (mRequestType == 2) { // For get image data
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
            S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucketName", mParams));
            S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(objectContent);

           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);



            mResult = "success";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        mResult = e.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPostExecute(result);
    mInterface.success(this.mResult);

}

public interface WebServiceInterface<E, R> {
    public void success(E reslut);

    public void error(R Error);
}

}
```

call this webservice any where in project

```
    WebserviceAmazon amazon = new WebserviceAmazon(getActivity(), imageName, "", 2);
    amazon.result(new WebserviceAmazon.WebServiceInterface<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String reslut) {

        }

        @Override
        public void error(String Error) {

        }
    });

    return totalPoints;
}
```

Comment: IS this possible for multiple files with looping ? I have multiple images to upload

Comment: I have 2  put only  PutObjectRequest request =... in looping right ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to do Two Steps;

1. Create the PutObjectRequestObject Like this:

> ```
> PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
>                               BUCKET_NAME, Key,
>                               stored);
>                       por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicReadWrite);
>
> s3Client.putObject(por);
> ```

2. Change the Policy Of Amazon s3 Server Console By Changing the bucket (Folder) Public.

I was already done that and it's working.